# Назначение цены для фич с приложения из ituness

Tags: ios, objective-c

Я заканчиваю первый проект, настройл in-app purchase в приложений, но цены для фич нужно добавлять в iTunesConnect подскажите как реализовать данную хитрость

Comment: идете в itunesconnect, выбираете ваше приложение (или создаете если еще не создали), идете в features -> in-app purchases, создаете какие вам надо покупки и ставите им цены

Comment: Ну без вас я никуда )) Max Mikheyenko - у меня колекция ячеек в них рисунки, эти рисунки продаются, цены для них нужно из itunesConnect добавить как я понял, но как это всё сделать, соединить с кодом не знаю так как это моё первое приложение

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial